# Switch case with an enum for button and labels

Tags: c#, winforms, button, switch-statement, label

I need to use a switch case with an enum.
I have 7 buttons and 7 labels. The first button is enabled, the others are disabled.
After i click the first button it should be disabled and the second one should be enabled.
How do i do this?

Comment: Could you clarify your question? Maybe provide a code example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are declaring an enum to keep track of which button you have enabled, such as:

```
public enum Buttons
{
  b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6, b7
}
Buttons CurrentButton = Buttons.b1;
```

you could then do the following:

```
switch (CurrentButton)
{
    case Buttons.b1:
        button1.Enabled = false;
        button2.Enabled = true;
        CurrentButton = Buttons.b2;
        break;
    case Buttons.b2:
        button2.Enabled = false;
        button3.Enabled = true;
        CurrentButton = Buttons.b3;
        break;
    {...}
}
```

Not sure if this was your thought process but it's one method. I would suggest other methods not using an enum however.